# How to reset a Task.Delay() after a event fired?

Tags: c#, delay, reset, filesystemwatcher

I am trying to let some code fire after my FileSystemWatcher hasn't received any changes for more then 5 minutes.

My current approach is to call a `await Task.Delay();` after a change, hoping the user is done by then. This obviously is **not** the way to go.

So my question: How to reset a Task.Delay() after a event fired?

Comment: A plain Timer has not gone out of style yet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't "reset" a `Task.Delay`, but you can reset a timer which makes it an ideal candidate to solve this problem.

Here's an example:

```
    private System.Threading.Timer timer;

    public void Start()
    {
        timer = new System.Threading.Timer(_ => fireMyCode());
        restartTimer();
    }

    private void onFileChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        restartTimer();
    }

    private void restartTimer()
    {
        timer.Change(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5), TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));
    }
```

But you don't have to use timers, you can still use `Task.Delay` with an additional task: the idea is to wait on two tasks, the delay and waiting for the files to change (you can use `TaskCompletionSource` to "create" a task from an event).
If the delay task completes first, fire your code.

Here's an example:

```
    TaskCompletionSource<object> fileChanged = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();

    private void onFileChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        fileChanged.TrySetResult(null);
    }

    private async Task endlessLoop()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            await handleFilesNotChanged();
        }
    }

    private async Task handleFilesNotChanged()
    {
        Task timeout = Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));
        Task waitForFile = fileChanged.Task;

        if (await Task.WhenAny(timeout, waitForFile) == timeout)
        {
            fireMyCode();
        }
        fileChanged = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
    }
```

Comment: What calls endlessLoop? And is it safe to loop it? I keep getting hangs with the following code even if making endlessLoop check to see if fireMyCode has finished.

Comment: What calls endlessLoop? Depending on the context of your application. For example, you can call it when clicking a button (a Windows Form example: private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await endlessLoop();
        }), is it safe to loop it? Do you mean, calling the endlessLoop function from within a loop? If that's the question, then no, you wouldn't want to do that, it's intended to run only once as it runs an endless loop itself.

Comment: I guess I'm confused as to why you have to loop it? IF you don't loop it does the Delay not continue? For some reason this code hangs my application. What starts timeout? How can timeout ever finish and hence equal any of the finished tasks? Why not call handleFilesNotChanged why do it through the loop?

Comment: In the first line it starts counting 5 minutes in a task called timeout. In the second line it starts waiting for a file change in a task called waitForFile. Those 2 now happen in parallel. When I do Task.WhenAny, the method will block until one of those tasks complete, and it returns the task that completed first. If the timeout task completed first, it means I've waited 5 minutes and no file has changed, so I "fire my code". However, if the file change completed first, everything is fine, but now I have to start my timer again, hence the loop. Without the loop this would only happen once.

Comment: If you have lots of file changes in rapid succession, you're going to have a heap o' timers sitting around for 5 minutes each. Eventually, they'll all expire and do nothing (since all their `WhenAny`s were already satisfied for each files changed). If the file changes quickly enough, in theory you could exhaust memory entirely. As least as the system grids to a halt, the file's not likely to keep changing so fast. :-) An implementation that freed the timer as soon as it was no longer useful would be better. One way it to cancel `timeout` when the file changes.