# Reset or Cancel the tasks delays on an event

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have write some code to run few tasks on the basis of a configuration list, Its working fine, but I have a new requirement where my configuration list timing can be change at run-time.

In that case i want to reset my task delay timing and cancel all the existing queue tasks, without restart the process.

If anyone can help me to achieve the same with more optimize code, I will be thankful.

Can any one help me to reset my task delay time on an event.

```
        private static void ResetProcessWithNewTime(RealTimeMessage message)
        {
            // Need some code to reset the timer of all task
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<RealTimeMessage> messages = GetRealTimeMessage();
            Parallel.ForEach(messages, (message) =>
            {
                processMessage(message);
            });

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static async void processMessage(RealTimeMessage message)
        {
            try
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(message.IntervalTime))
                    ProceesRequest(message);

                while (true)
                {
                    double taskIntervalTime = GetTaskInterval(message);
                    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(taskIntervalTime));
                    await Task.Run(() => ProceesRequest(message));
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Critical error on startup unable to send startup message");
            }
        }

        private static void ProceesRequest(RealTimeMessage message)
        {
            Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
            if (!stopwatch.IsRunning)
            {
                stopwatch.Start();

                //After excution
                Console.WriteLine(message.MessageText + " is running @ " + DateTime.Now);
                //

                stopwatch.Stop();
            }
        }
        private static double GetTaskInterval(RealTimeMessage message)
        {
            double delayTime;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(message.IntervalTime))
                delayTime = Convert.ToInt64(message.IntervalTime) * 60;
            else
                delayTime = GetNextTime(message.TimeOfDay);

            return delayTime;
        }

        private static double GetNextTime(string timeOfDay)
        {
            IEnumerable<TimeSpan> timeSpans = timeOfDay.Split(',').Select(x => TimeSpan.Parse(x));
            TimeSpan timeSpan = timeSpans.FirstOrDefault(x => x > DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay);
            return timeSpan.Subtract(DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay).TotalSeconds;
        }


        private static List<RealTimeMessage> GetRealTimeMessage()
        {
            List<RealTimeMessage> realTimeMessages = new List<RealTimeMessage>();
            realTimeMessages.Add(new RealTimeMessage { MessageText = "Message 1", IntervalTime = "", MessageType = "Connect", TimeOfDay = "10:20,12:30,22:40" });
            realTimeMessages.Add(new RealTimeMessage { MessageText = "Message 2", IntervalTime = "", MessageType = "AIDX_Version9_1", TimeOfDay = "10:20,12:30,22:40" });
            realTimeMessages.Add(new RealTimeMessage { MessageText = "Message 3", IntervalTime = "", MessageType = "AIDX_Version14_1", TimeOfDay = "10:20,12:30,22:40" });
            realTimeMessages.Add(new RealTimeMessage { MessageText = "Message 4", IntervalTime = "15", MessageType = "AIDX_Version16_1", TimeOfDay = "" });
            realTimeMessages.Add(new RealTimeMessage { MessageText = "Message 5", IntervalTime = "20", MessageType = "AMSX", TimeOfDay = "" });

            return realTimeMessages;
        }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to reset a Task.Delay() after a event fired?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33259647/how-to-reset-a-task-delay-after-a-event-fired)

Comment: No, I have seen this link and Its not resolving my problem because I will get new time schedule for a task from GetRealTimeMessage().

Comment: that's exactly the use case for a `Timer`, you can call `timer.Change(GetRealTimeMessage().NewIntervalInMelliseconds)`